# Vim colors do not appear correctly in tmux terminal running within rxvt-unicode terminal

Tags: linux, vim, debian, tmux, urxvt

I am using Debian (Jessie).

My ~/.vimrc file contains the following statement.

```
colorscheme murphy
```

My ~/.Xresources file contains the following properties.

```
URxvt.background: #000000
URxvt.foreground: #e0e0e0
URxvt.scrollBar: false
URxvt.borderless: true
URxvt.font:xft:Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:pixelsize=16
```

When I launch `vim` within my rxvt-unicode terminal (`urxvt`) I get the expected output.

[image: Vim running within rxvt-unicode]

But when I launch `tmux` within `urxvt` and then launch `vim` within the tmux terminal, the colours are too bright.

[image: Vim running within tmux running within rxvt-unicode]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurs because the rxvt-unicode (urxvt) terminal supports only 88 colours whereas tmux terminal supports 256.

Output from urxvt:

```
susam@nifty:~$ tput colors
88
```

As a result, when tmux starts, it uses only 8 colours

```
susam@nifty:~$ tput colors
8
```

Adding the following tmux command to ~/.tmux.conf doesn't help.

```
set -g default-terminal screen-256color
```

With that line in ~/.tmux.conf, when tmux starts, it seems to be using 256 colours.

```
susam@nifty:~$ tput colors
256
```

However, it doesn't help because although tmux seems to be using 256 colours, the underlying rxvt-unicode (urxvt) terminal cannot display them properly since it supports only 88 colours. As a result, Vim still displays colours that are too bright.

**Solution: Install rxvt-unicode-256color package.**

There is an rxvt-unicode-256color package available in Debian that comes with urxvt terminal that supports 256 colours. Installing rxvt-unicode-256color fixed the issue.

The commands I used:

```
aptitude update
aptitude purge rxvt-unicode
aptitude install rxvt-unicode-256color
```

The colours appear a little bit different now.

[image]

But the experience is consistent with tmux.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! See my answer on how to fix highlighting and italics.

Answer (score 0):

Susam Pal's answer is great and worked for me.  I still had a small issue with it, however, as *man* highlighted search results in *italics*.  According to the last entry in the [tmux-FAQ](http://tmux.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux/tmux/FAQ):

> Screen's terminfo description *lacks italics mode* and has standout mode
>   in its place, but using *the same escape sequence that urxvt uses for italics*.

Here's how to fix this issue from the terminal (adapted from the FAQ):

```sh
$ mkdir $HOME/.terminfo/
$ screen_terminfo="screen-256color"
$ infocmp "$screen_terminfo" | sed \
  -e 's/^screen[^|]*|[^,]*,/screen-it-256color|screen with italics support,/' \
  -e 's/%?%p1%t;3%/%?%p1%t;7%/' \
  -e 's/smso=[^,]*,/smso=\\E[7m,/' \
  -e 's/rmso=[^,]*,/rmso=\\E[27m,/' \
  -e '$s/$/ sitm=\\E[3m, ritm=\\E[23m,/' > /tmp/screen.terminfo
$ tic /tmp/screen.terminfo
```

Then, change the following tmux line in ~/.tmux.conf:

```
set -g default-terminal screen-it-256color
```